# Android debugging on devices with lower APIs

Tags: android, debugging

Today I start debugging in the source code of android on device which is with API 17, but I compile with API 22. So I tell AS to compile with API 17. I do this, because in API 22 source code is different and debugging sending me in comments etc. inappropriate places in code. But when I try to compile on API 17 I start to get errors. For example, because custom views in API 17 should have 3 constructor, but in API 22 we have 4. And the fourth one was the problem for compiling. I comment it and it is worked, but what if I have 100 custom views in the project ? How can I debug on an older device? Is there an easier way compared to this (to comment all code which is for the new versions). 
I hope that I explain clearly my question.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you "debugging in the source code of android"? Are you building a custom ROM?

Comment: No, I just don't know why one function returns true, so I want to start debugging and to see why. It's actually pretty hard to me to understand something from the source code. That was the reason. Actually debugging is not the appropriate word - lets say investigate :D . 
Thanks for your attention.